# Assign variable to a variable with a string in R

Tags: r

Say I have `type1 <- "M"`

and `myvec <- c(2,4,6,8)`

How can I assign `myvec` to `type1` so when I just  type `M`, I could get `myvec` elements?

Is there something like `assign(type1) <- myvec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assign(type1, myvec)
```

Will assign the variable indicated by `type1` (`"M"`) to the value contained in `myvec`.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to use `<-`, an option is to select the environment (in this case the `.GlobalEnv` and use `[[` for assignment

```
.GlobalEnv[[type1]] <- myvec
M
#[1] 2 4 6 8
```